# Map List into Tuples?

Tags: python, lambda, mapping, tuples, iterable

I'm trying to map a list of lines into tuples with line number and line length. My instructions require me to use the map, filter, and reduce functionalities in Python.

So far I've got filter, which is here.

```
def code_metric(file):
    x = filter(lambda x : x != "\n", open(file))
    y = map(lambda x: )
```

Sample of how it should look like ...

(1, # of chars in line)

I'm having trouble mapping the list into line numbers and line length using the map function.

Comment: you want to calculate the length of a line and store it in a tuple with the iteration number?

Comment: Yes. I've got this so far ...

tester = map(lambda x : (x[0] + 1, len(x[1])),  enumerate(txt))

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
map(lambda x:(x[0], len(x[1])), enumerate(open('your_file'), start=1))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I ended up getting after your guys' answer helped me deduce it.

```
filtered = map(lambda x : (1, len(x.strip('\n'))), mapper)
```

The first value in the tuple was supposed to be default '1' (sorry guys!)

Answer (score 0):

```
def code_metric(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        metric = list(enumerate(map(len, f), 1))
    return metric
```

This function will do what you want. Could you explain how `lambda` and `reduce` could be relevant to this functionality?